# VBA Excel String Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, string, type-mismatch

I'm in Excel but extracting data from many similar but slightly different word documents...

The code below is supposed to look at the TITLE of the first Table : WTab(1) in the Word document. And if it contains the text "Round 1" I want to extract the Data from THAT Table.

If the Text is NOT in the title then I need to use WTab(2) instead.

The following Code is producing a Type Mismatch - But I cant figure why...

```
Rnd_Search = WTab(1).Range.Paragraphs(1).Previous.Range.Text
    If InStr(Rnd_Search, "round 1", 1) = 0 Then
        StartTble = 2
    Else
        StartTble = 1
    End If
```

I then use the expression:

```
WTab(StartTble)
```

Definitions are as follows:

```
Set WApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WDoc = WApp.Documents.Open(PathName)
Set WTab = WDoc.Tables
Dim StartTbl As Integer
```

Any ideas you wonderful array of Legends!

Stu

Comment: Could you give us more details? What's the context of using this macro, what data you use? What are you trying to approach? Besides, you marked your post as Excel VBA. Are you sure it's not Word VBA?

Comment: If you specify the compare mode for `Instr`, you have to include the start position, so it needs to be: `InStr(1, Rnd_Search, "round 1", 1)`

Comment: @Konrad I've included a bit more context.. does this help?
I could post the entire code... but everything Else is working great

Comment: It helped, thanks. Nevertheless, I think @Rory has already given you an answer.

Comment: @Rory - That did it.. But do you know why?
According to the documentation, the start position is optional?

Comment: It's only optional if you don't use the last argument. Don't know why to be honest.

Comment: @Rory Weird.. But thank you

Comment: You `Dim StartTbl` but you `StartTble = 2` spot the additional `e`. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`!

Comment: @StuFisher The [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) documentation did specify that `start` argument is required *if* you specify the `compare` argument. Alternatively you can compare the lower/upper-ed version of both strings and omit the `compare` argument e.g. `InStr(LCase(Rnd_Search), "round 1")`

Comment: Please also check this link: [complete explanation how InStr works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100221/vba-compile-error-if-instr-function-used-with-named-parameter-and-return-value-a). It seems this simple function is more messed up than we think